# Error loading Xfce on FreeBSD in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, xorg, freebsd, xfce, xfce4

I typed startxfce4, but it showed the error message:

> failed to set mtrr: Device not configured
>
> process 1675: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed
>
> to open "/etc/machine-id": No such file or directory
>
> See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to forrect this issue
>
> D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace Abort trap (core dumped) xinit: connection to X server lost
>
> waiting for X server to shut down failed to unset mtrr: Device not configured

How do I configure the device for mtrr?

I also tried

I also tried "cd /usr/ports/x11-wm/xfce4" so that I could type "make install clean" but it showed:

> /usr/ports/x11-wm/xfce4: No such file or directory

What's wrong? I looked for a solution on the Internet with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the D-Bus service.

Put `dbus_enable=YES` into [/etc/rc.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?rc.conf). If it does not help then run `dbus-uuidgen --ensure` to generate the missing `/etc/machine-id`.

When it comes to ports, however: you have to download the ports tree first. It shouldn't be required to build XFCE from ports to solve the `/etc/machine-id` problem, though.

PS This issue might go away entirely in the future when [this revision](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D15324) is merged into FreeBSD

---

References:

- [devel/dbus: Applications segfault due to missing machine-id after package install](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228001)
- [FreeBSD Handbook: Using the Ports Collection](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html)
- [FreeBSD Wiki: Graphics FAQ](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Graphics/FAQ#A.22D-Bus_library_appears_to_be_incorrectly_set_up.3B_failed_to_read_machine_uuid:_Failed_to_open_.22.2Fetc.2Fmachine-id.22:_No_such_file_or_directory.22)
- [*XDM not allowing me to log in as any user* on FreeBSD Forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/xdm-not-allowing-me-to-log-in-as-any-user.60056/#post-344979)

Comment: I actually figured it out before you posted this answer. I have to enable and start dbus. I read https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/xdm-not-allowing-me-to-log-in-as-any-user.60056/. I don't know of any way to link to the exact section of the page that says "Enable and start the D-Bus daemon: sysrc dbus_enable=YES && service dbus start"

Comment: @JonathanDahlin I added the link to the comment + to the pull request which is going to fix this issue forever. :) Cheers